# how to deselect row by clicking outside tableWidget pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I get the selected line with the

```
row = self.table.currentRow()
```

but when I click outside the tableWidget it keeps the last currentRow, how do I click anywhere outside the tableWidget the currentRow goes back to -1 and deselect the line

Comment: Your question is unclear, and I'm under the impression that you might be facing an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please try to explain what you're trying to achieve, why you need to "clear" the current index and what would be its final purpose.

Comment: I have a tableWidget, and with it a delete button, which will check which row is selected to delete, but if I select it and I don't want to delete anymore, I want the row to be deselected and the currentRow to be -1 again

Comment: `self.table.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())`

Comment: musicamante I love you man, that was exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the musicamante.

```
self.table.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())
```

it's exactly what I needed